# What this CSS code means (font-size division)?

Tags: css

Sorry everyone, I really can't find any better title for my question.

I have encountered with this code

```
font: 9pt/18px Tahoma;
```

Do you know what it means?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes. It's a short-hand way of writing `font-size` and `line-height` together.

Answer (score 14):

```
/* The shorthand */
font: 9pt/18px Tahoma;

/* The expanded version of the above style */
font-size:9pt;
line-height:18px;
font-family:Tahoma;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the font-size and line-height when you're using shorthand for the font declaration. So 9pt font-size and 18px line-height.

Answer (score 3):

The first unit is font-size, the second is line-height.