# What does 16px/28px mean in a css font rule?

Tags: css, font-size

I keep on seeing font styles like `font: 16px/28px 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;` and I just can't find out what the `16px/28px` could mean. Why are there two different font sizes defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What this css code means(font-size division)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395013/what-this-css-code-meansfont-size-division)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sets both the font size and the line height.

See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font)'s example :

> /*Set the font size to 12px and the line height to 14px. Set the font family to sans-serif */
>
> p { font: 12px/14px sans-serif }

Answer (score 2):

`16px/28px` = Font-size and line height respectively

**http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand**