# CSS: What/why specify font-size as font-size: 14px/1.31em?

Tags: css

In CSS, I've seen setting the font-size using *both* px and em as below:

```
font-size: 14px/1.31em;
```

What exactly does this way of writing mean and what problem do I solve by using this way of writing?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What this css code means(font-size division)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395013/what-this-css-code-meansfont-size-division)

Comment: Actually, I realized the key difference here is that the possible duplicate references the `font` property, as opposed to `font-size`. `font-size: 14px/1.31em` is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the exact definition of `em` and `px`

`Ems` (em): The “em” is a scalable unit that is used in web document media. An em is equal to the current font-size, for instance, if the font-size of the document is 12pt, 1em is equal to 12pt. Ems are scalable in nature, so 2em would equal 24pt, .5em would equal 6pt, etc. Ems are becoming increasingly popular in web documents due to scalability and their mobile-device-friendly nature.

`Pixels` (px): Pixels are fixed-size units that are used in screen media (i.e. to be read on the computer screen). One pixel is equal to one dot on the computer screen (the smallest division of your screen’s resolution). Many web designers use pixel units in web documents in order to produce a pixel-perfect representation of their site as it is rendered in the browser. One problem with the pixel unit is that it does not scale upward for visually-impaired readers or downward to fit mobile devices.

---

> What exactly does this way of writing mean and what problem do I solve by using this way of writing?

When you set your `font-size` equal to 10px, for example, and you use the 3em. You will get 30px (10*3).

**EDIT:**

Basically, we can use `font: 14/1.31em`, which is a short-hand, to set the `font-size` and `line-height`.

However, in your case, `font-size: 14px/1.31em;` doesn't have any short-hand. So, you cannot set it this way. **It is a wrong syntax**.

See more explanation of ["CSS Font-Size"](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Comment: `you will get 14px/1.31*your current font-size` .... no you won't. The `/` is not a division sign. CSS doesn't do math, unless you use `calc()`.

Comment: @Spudley You are right. I get used to write the `LESS`. So, in this case, it is invalid syntax for cSS.