# Font-size CSS parameter looks like font-size:181.25%16px;

Tags: html, css, font-size, w3c-validation

We've run into a CSS style-sheet where some of the values for `font-size` parameter are defined as **font-size:181.25%16px**.

Separatetly these are well understood: relative (scaling to 29px) and absolute values, but mixing them together...? For what purpose?

I briefly read through the newest W3C specs but I couldn't find this form of encoding. Google Chrome perfectly validates it and correctly displays a document with a single tag: `<p style="font-size:181.25%16px">Test</p>`

**NOTE:** The reference to [What this CSS code means (font-size division)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395013/what-this-css-code-meansfont-size-division) is ambiguous because in the reference post `font: 9pt/18px Tahoma;` means just a short-hand way of writing `font-size` and `line-height` together.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What this css code means(font-size division)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395013/what-this-css-code-meansfont-size-division)

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate, but actually it isn't -- I mis-read it, and actually your code is a plain and simple syntax error. However, the duplicate does show what the original coder might have been intending to do, so it's worth keeping the link there.

Comment: Not a duplicate. In the reference post `font: 9pt/18px Tahoma;` means `font-size` and `line-height` written together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a syntax error.

[image: Validator error]

Chrome marks it as ignored.

[image: Chrome view]